# Reference to tcolorbox environment with counter in beamer

Tags: cross-referencing, tcolorbox

Thanks to Schrödinger's cat, I have been using the [following environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQMWu.png).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\def\tcb@proc@counter@auto#1{%
  \newcounter{tcb@cnt@#1}%
  \csxdef{tcb@cnt@#1}{tcb@cnt@#1}%
  \tcb@proc@counter@autoanduse{#1}%
  \ifcsname resetcounteronoverlays\endcsname%<-added
  \resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@#1}%<-added
  \fi%<-added
}
\makeatother
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{numberedbox}[2][]{%
colback=green!5,colframe=green!40!black,center,title=Numbered
box~\thetcbcounter: #2,#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
%\frametitle{tcolorboxes}
\begin{numberedbox}[label={boxA}]{title A}
I am random box and have number~\ref{boxA}
\end{numberedbox}
\pause
\begin{numberedbox}[label={catinbox}]{A cat in a box}
\dots wrote this, see numbered box~\ref{boxA}
\end{numberedbox}
\pause
\begin{numberedbox}[label={yetanotherbox}]{title B}
I'm boring, see numbered box~\ref{catinbox} for something exciting
\end{numberedbox}

I want to refer to box \ref{
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

If I enter the correct label name, it works. But TeXstudio does not suggest possible labels when I type `\ref{}`. Sometimes, the label name is long and I have to track it back in a long document which is inconvenient.

As seen in the screen capture below, when I tried to refer to the boxes, their labels did not show up. Is it possible to make that happen?

[image]

Comment: I see. OK, I feel that you should really prominently mention TeXstudio in your question, and explain the issue. I delete my answer.

Comment: I updated my question to make it clearer.